# Using BibTeX with letter class

Tags: bibtex, letters

I'm trying to use BibTeX with a letter; I hope this is not too eccentric. The letter class doesn't have BibTeX support, though. I found  [Environment thebibliography undefined when using letter](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3359). However, the solution described does not work perfectly. The bibliography appears on its own page (in my case it is just two entries), and the numbering is out of order with the plain style ie. [2] appears before [1] in the letter.

Can these issues be fixed? Alternatively, what are my choices? Could I use another letter class? Some time ago I posted to comp.text.tex, and the people there were rather despising about the letter class, and pointed me to various alternatives which they said were better. Do any of these alternatives have built-in BibTeX support?

EDIT1: Both the problems mentioned above were user error.

1. The wrong order, as pointed out by Joseph, was because I was using the `plain`
    style.
2. The bibliography on a separate page was because I put the `\bibliographystyle`
    and `\bibliography` entries after closing the `letter` environment instead of
    before. Again, Joseph's example was helpful in setting me straight.

In summary, there is nothing wrong with the original post, though no doubt Joseph's version is an improvement, and is certainly shorter. Both the original version and Joseph's version work fine for me. I put the text in Joseph's post between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` into a separate sty file when using it with my letter.

EDIT2: Adding `\usepackage{natbib}` to the preamble breaks the compile. Whether I put it before or after the "homemade" bib sty file doesn't make a difference. I get

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Environment thebibliography undefined.
```

Comment: See my update - for me `natbib` is fine

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Taking the definition from the `article` class, I get good results with

```
\begin{filecontents}{letter.bib}
@article{First,
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  title   = "Some things {I} did",
  journal = "J. Irreproducible Results",
  year    = "2011"
}

@article{Second,
  author  = "Aaa, S{\o}mebloke",
  title   = "Tigers",
  journal = "Ann. Improbable Res.",
  year    = "2011"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{letter}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Some person}
\opening{Hello}

Some text \cite{First}, more text \cite{Second}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{letter}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I've used the `unsrt` style here, as `plain` would put the references in alphabetical rather than citation order. I've also modified the definition of `thebiliography` a little, removing the section-related stuff as this does not really seem relevant to a letter. (I also took out the code related to the `openbib` option for the `article` class, again as it does not seem relevant.)

---

The second edit to the question asks about `natbib`. For me, this works if I load `natbib` after defining `thebiliography` and if I make `\bibsection` 'safe':

```
\begin{filecontents}{letter.bib}
@article{First,
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  title   = "Some things {I} did",
  journal = "J. Irreproducible Results",
  year    = "2011"
}

@article{Second,
  author  = "Aaa, S{\o}mebloke",
  title   = "Tigers",
  journal = "Ann. Improbable Res.",
  year    = "2011"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{letter}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\makeatother
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\let\bibsection\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Some person}
\opening{Hello}

Some text \cite{First}, more text \cite{Second}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{letter}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (The `filecontents` environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. bibtex seems unhappy with your entries though. I get errors like `Warning--string name "``other" is undefined
--line 6 of file letter.bib
I was expecting an "="---line 6 of file letter.bib
 :   author  = ``other, a. 
 :                         N.'',
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--string name "``aaa" is undefined
--line 13 of file letter.bib
"{" immediately follows a field name---line 13 of file letter.bib
 :   author  = ``aaa, S
 :                     {\o}mebloke'',
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
`

Comment: @Faheem: This is WFM exactly as posted on Windows. From your post, it looks like your editor might have changed the `"` in my example code into 'pretty printing' LaTeX ligatures, which of course will not work. Try creating your own `.bib` file directly using whatever editor you usually prefer for that. It's only an example, after all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I assuming making \bibsection 'safe' corresponds to the line `\let\bibsection\relax`? So, I was wondering how one would manage if one wanted to stick the letter bib code into a separate style file, as this relax command comes after the import of `natbib`. Also, could you explain what this relax command does?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I think that I found a more elegant and more extensive solution.

The developers of [komascript.de](http://www.komascript.de/) provide a class `scrartcl` that is basically equivalent to the standard article class but allows the integration of letters.  The beauty is, you cannot only print a bibliography but also use sections and other tools that you might have missed from the article class.  A working example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{letter.bib}
@article{First,
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  title   = "Some things {I} did",
  journal = "J. Irreproducible Results",
  year    = "2011"
}

@article{Second,
  author  = "Aaa, S{\o}mebloke",
  title   = "Tigers",
  journal = "Ann. Improbable Res.",
  year    = "2011"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name of Sender}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address of Sender}
\begin{letter}{Name of Recipient\\Address of Recipient}
  \opening{Dear Recipient,}

  \section{Interesting Stuff}
  The first~\cite{First} citation.
  \lipsum%

  \section{Another Citation}
  And the second~\cite{Second} citation.

  \closing{Yours sincerely,}

  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  \bibliography{letter}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I've also become a fan of the KOMA classes. They're not perfect, but they are much more flexible than the default `letter` and `article` classes. I now use `scrlttr2` as my default letter class. Thanks for the answer. I'm unclear what the `scrletter` class is for, though.

Comment: `scrletter` is a relatively new package that provides the `letter` environment that can be used within the custom article class `scrartcl`.

Comment: I see. That sounds useful.