# How to use Bibtex with G-Brief

Tags: bibtex, letters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BibTeX with letter class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/using-bibtex-with-letter-class)

My goal is to write a letter using the `g-brief` package including some references using the `\cite{}` and the `\bibliography{}` commands. For this, I've written a `.bib` file which contains the necessary bibtex entries. After compiling the file with `latex file.tex` the following error message occurs:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment thebibliography undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{thebibliography}
                           {}
```

This is the content of the file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,latin1]{g-brief}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

...some text...

\bibliography{bib}{}
\end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```

I tried to do the following steps without success:

- including the cite package via `\usepackage{cite}`
- to put the `\bibligraphystyle{}` command inside the document (I think this does not work anyways)
- to put the `\bibligraphy{}` command outside the `g-brief` environment

It would be nice if someone could help with including references in a `g-brief`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `g-brief` is outdated.

For a proper letter in German language you should bettter use KOMA-Script and the class `scrlttr2`. It has many advantages and a very good German description. You can personalise your letters with a `lco` file containing your personal dates and use this `lco` file for all your letters.

I've never tried to include a bibliography in `scrlttr2` so at the moment I can't say whether it is running or not.

Comment: The formatting of my answer here was a bit confusing, so I will give a comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok. As I cannot answer my own question before 8 hours after asking, I will try to explain my problem here.

I tried the scrlttr2 documentclass but without success. The first compilation with pdflatex or latex works fine. The bibtex compilation also works fine. But then, by compiling again using pdflatex or latex I get the same error like in my first post.

So it seems to me that the scrlttr2 documentclass does not help me either. But as g-brief is outdated I will use scrlttr2 in future.

Comment: I tried to indent the code by 4 spaces. But the code was not highlighted and without line breaks. Nevertheless, I hope the text above is enough for the explanaition of my problem.