# Bibliography in letter class?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, letters

Is it possible to add a list of references at the end of the text in the 'letter' documentclass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BibTeX with letter class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18033). The simple answer is no, but there are things you can do.  The standard letter class is very limited.  On this more general issue, see [Letter class alternatives with support for figures, tables, and labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25061).

Comment: Don't use Bibtex.  The form for references is not that difficult.