# Is it possible to use titling package with letter class?

Tags: incompatibility, letters, titling

An attempt to use the package `titling` with the class `letter`:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{titling}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\thetitle\par
\theauthor\par
\thedate\par
Text.

\end{document}
```

results in errors indicating that they are incompatible:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. \if@titlepage
> Extra \else. \else
> Extra \fi. \fi
> Extra \fi.
> ```

This can be avoided by, e.g., not invoking `titling` and instead referring to `\@title`, `\@author`, and `\@date`.

Nevertheless, I am interested if there is a way to patch some of the conflicting class/package definitions to maintain the possibility to use the macros provided by `titling` in `letter`? I have not found any information about this matter neither in the documentation of the class and the package nor on TeX.SX.

Comment: Unrelated: `scrletter` package could be an alternative solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/using-bibtex-with-letter-class).

Comment: Why specifically do you want to use the `letter` class? You can perform similar layouts using just `article`. If you want to show what you're after, one can reproduce it.

Comment: I am currently editing several documents of `newlfm` class (that inherits this problem after `letter`). They use its features like `\newlfmP`, `\addr…`, `\name…` `\closeline` or `\psitem`. It is possible to recreate them using `article`, although the effort needed to achieve satisfactory results for a few documents in different layouts would be incomparably higher than just giving up on `titling` and using `\@title` etc. I was just curious about the reason for this incompatibility, as sometimes just a single use of, e.g., `\patchcommand` could solve such errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the basic document classes ([`article`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)), except for [`letter`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls?view=co) (and [`minimal`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls?view=co)) define the option to have a title page with an accompanying conditional `\if@titlepage`. Since `letter` doesn't declare this conditional, you can intervene:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}

% Define conditional used by most document classes
\expandafter\newif\csname if@titlepage\endcsname
\usepackage{titling}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\thetitle\par
\theauthor\par
\thedate\par
Text.

\end{document}
```